# remove specific field javascript

Tags: javascript, appendchild, removechild

I have an form with some inputs. When i click on the + button, javascript create an input field. This is my form code:

```
 <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div id="container">
            <div id="new" class="">
                <input type="number" name="number" id="number"> 
                <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                    <option>4</option>
                </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button onClick="addNumber(); New();" class="btn btn-warning btn-md" type="button">+</button>
```

The + button create an new option and number field. This is the Javascript code for create new fields:

```
   function New()
  {
    var node = document.createElement("div");
    node.setAttribute("id", "new");
    node.setAttribute("class", addNumber());
    node.innerHTML = $("#new").html();
    document.getElementById("container").appendChild(node);
    $('#container').append(node);
}
```

This works good, but i want delete an specific field. When the new field create's, i want also when the delete button clicked, the field deleted. How can i do this?

Comment: please add what you have tried so far and why that doesn't work

Comment: When an new field creates he get an class with an number. In het javascript i've tried: function deleteItem()
    {
     var id;
     id = document.getElementById('new').className;
     alert(id);
   } But i don't get an class id in the alert.

Comment: wrap input and select into a div and add dynamic id to that div.

Comment: @lakhvirkumar How can i create an wrap input?

Comment: ok you already create a div new.. you just need to asign a dynamic id to with 'new-1' like this

Comment: add a var count =1 . and increment it everytime you add a new element. and add this to div id node.setAttribute("id", "new_" + count);

Comment: When the button clicked, there create an new id like "new2" "new4" etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

now add delete icon with every div and on click pass id of that div to dlete function

Comment: function delete(divId) {
div = document.getElementByid(divId);
// login to delete div here
}

Comment: It works, in my delete function i have the following code: n.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(n.parentNode); and he delete the specific id!